# problem with bi-directional video conferencing webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Thanks in advance.

I am following the guide to implement webrtc from the official page:

https://webrtc.org/

And I am having trouble for two-way communication. On one pc I have a video camera and on the other only a microphone.

I manage to receive the camcorder, but I cannot receive the .ontrack event on the pc that sends the camcorder and it has to receive only the audio, when I am adding the track on the computer that sends the audio but not launch event .ontrack on remote machine.

The connection is made correctly, here paste the connection and the code

MY CODE one one localhost/video.php antother localhsot/video.php?cliente=1

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Jesús
 * Date: 16/03/2020
 * Time: 13:16
 */
 ?>

<video id="localVideo" autoplay <?= !isset($_GET['cliente']) ? 'muted' : '' ?> playsinline controls="false" style="width: 600px; height: 320px;"></video>

<?php
if(!isset($_GET['cliente'])) {
?>
<button onclick="makeCallAdmin()">enviar llamada</button>
<?php
}
?>

<script src="../app/js/lib/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>

    let cliente = <?= isset($_GET['cliente']) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>;
    let tipo = cliente ? 'client' : 'admin';

    var ipSocket = 'SCOCKETADDRESS';
    // var ipSocket = 'https://192.168.125.175:3001';
    var idgrupo = '5ed44424c2df0470d689.4f6370fbe1ac319e5dc1d7417822d28a';

    var socket = io(ipSocket, {
        query: "grupo=" + idgrupo + "&tipo=" + tipo
    });


    const iceConfiguration = {
        iceServers: [
            {

                urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302?transport=udp'
            },
            {

                urls: 'turns:turnserver',
                username: 'prueba',
                credential: '123456'
            }
        ],
    }

    const offerOptions = {
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
    };

    // let peerConnection, remoteStream, videoElement;
    let peerConnection;
    let fuerzaConectar;



    async function getConnectedDevices(type) {
        const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        return await devices.filter(device => device.kind === type)
    }

    // Open camera with at least minWidth and minHeight capabilities
    async function openCamera(cameraId, audioid) {

        let constraints;

        if(!cameraId) {
            constraints = {
                'audio': {'echoCancellation': true}
            }

        }else{
            constraints = {
                'audio': {'echoCancellation': true},
                'video': {
                    'deviceId': cameraId
                }
            }
        }

        // constraints = {'video': true, 'audio': true};

        return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    }

    async function playVideoFromCamera(peerConnection, type, fuerza) {
        if(type == null)
            type = 'videoinput';
        if(fuerza == null)
            fuerza = false;

        try {
            const cameras = await getConnectedDevices(type);
            if (cameras && cameras.length > 0) {

                let stream;

                if(fuerza) //si solo ha encontrado el audio enviamos solo audio
                    stream = await openCamera(false, cameras[0].deviceId);
                else //si ha encontrado camara enviamos camara y audio
                    stream = await openCamera(cameras[0].deviceId, false);

                stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                    peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
                });


            }else{
                if(!fuerza)
                    await playVideoFromCamera(peerConnection, 'audioinput', true);
                else
                    console.log('no hay input');
            }

        } catch(error) {
            console.error('Error opening video camera.', error);
        }
    }


    async function makeCallAdmin() {

        fuerzaConectar = (fuerzaConectar == null | !fuerzaConectar) ? true : false;

        if(typeof peerConnection == 'object') {
            peerConnection.close();
            peerConnection = null;
            const videoElement = document.querySelector('video#localVideo');
            videoElement.srcObject = null;
            if(cliente)
                socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeCliente');
            else
                socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin');
        }

        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

        const remoteStream = new MediaStream();


        // Listen for local ICE candidates on the local RTCPeerConnection
        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('icecandidate', iceCandidate);
        // peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', iceCandidate);
        peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => iceCandidate(e);

        // Listen for connectionstatechange on the local RTCPeerConnection
        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', iceconnectionstatechange);
        peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => iceconnectionstatechange(e, peerConnection);

        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('track', track);
        // peerConnection.addEventListener('track', trackEv);
        peerConnection.ontrack =  e => trackEv(e, remoteStream);




        socket.on('videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin', data => videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin(data, peerConnection));

        const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer(offerOptions);
        await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        socket.emit('videoconferenciaAdmin', {'tipo':'remoteDescription','offer': offer});
    }

    async function makeCallCliente() 
    {

        fuerzaConectar = (fuerzaConectar == null | !fuerzaConectar) ? true : false;

        if(typeof peerConnection == 'object') {
            peerConnection.close();
            peerConnection = null;
            const videoElement = document.querySelector('video#localVideo');
            videoElement.srcObject = null;
            if(cliente)
                socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeCliente');
            else
                socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin');
        }

        peerConnection = await new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

        const remoteStream = await new MediaStream();


        // Listen for local ICE candidates on the local RTCPeerConnection
        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('icecandidate', iceCandidate);
        // peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', iceCandidate);
        peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => iceCandidate(e);

        // Listen for connectionstatechange on the local RTCPeerConnection
        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', iceconnectionstatechange);
        peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => iceconnectionstatechange(e, peerConnection);

        // peerConnection.removeEventListener('track', track);
        // peerConnection.addEventListener('track', trackEv);
        peerConnection.ontrack =  e => trackEv(e, remoteStream);



        socket.on('videoconferenciaRecibeCliente', data => videoconferenciaRecibeCliente(data, peerConnection, ));



    }

    async function videoconferenciaRecibeCliente(data, peerConnection)
    {

        switch(data.tipo) {
            case 'remoteDescription':
                if (data.offer) {
                    console.log(data.offer);
                    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(data.offer));
                    const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer(offerOptions);
                    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

                    await socket.emit('videoconferenciaCliente', {'tipo':'remoteDescription','answer': answer});
                    console.log('recibida conexion cliente');
                    console.log(peerConnection);
                }
                break;
            case 'icecandidate':
                if (data.icecandidate) {
                    try {
                        await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.icecandidate);
                        console.log('creado ice candidate cliente');
                        console.log(data.icecandidate);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }


    }

    async function videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin(data, peerConnection)
    {

        switch(data.tipo) {
            case 'remoteDescription':
                if (data.answer) {
                    console.log(data.answer);
                    const remoteDesc = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
                    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
                    console.log('recibida conexion admin');
                    console.log(peerConnection);
                }
                break;
            case 'icecandidate':
                if (data.icecandidate) {
                    try {
                        await peerConnection.addIceCandidate(data.icecandidate);
                        console.log('creado ice candidate admin');
                        console.log(data.icecandidate);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Error adding received ice candidate', e);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    async function iceCandidate(event)
    {

        let el_evento = cliente ? 'videoconferenciaCliente' : 'videoconferenciaAdmin';

        if (event.candidate) {
            socket.emit(el_evento, {'tipo':'icecandidate','icecandidate': event.candidate});
        }

    }

    async function iceconnectionstatechange(event, peerConnection)
    {

        console.log(peerConnection.iceConnectionState);

        switch(peerConnection.iceConnectionState) {
            case 'connected':
                console.log('CONECTADO');
                await enviarLLamada(peerConnection);
                switch(true) {
                    case fuerzaConectar && cliente:
                        // makeCallCliente();
                        break;
                    case fuerzaConectar && !cliente:
                        makeCallAdmin();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 'disconnected':
                console.log('DESconectado');
                await peerConnection.close();
                peerConnection = null;
                const videoElement = document.querySelector('video#localVideo');
                videoElement.srcObject = null;
                if(cliente)
                    await socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeCliente');
                else
                    await socket.off('videoconferenciaRecibeAdmin');


                break;
        }

    }

    async function trackEv(event, remoteStream)
    {

        const videoElement = document.querySelector('video#localVideo');
        if(videoElement.srcObject == null)
            videoElement.srcObject = remoteStream;

        console.log('entra a TRACK');
        await remoteStream.addTrack(event.track, remoteStream);
        // videoElement.play();
    }

    async function enviarLLamada(peerConnection)
    {

        await playVideoFromCamera(peerConnection);

    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        if(cliente)
            makeCallCliente();
        // else
        //     makeCallAdmin();

    });





</script>
```